# SailsJs nothing happen after calling save method

Tags: node.js, promise, sails.js

Sorry, this is my first nodeJs app, I'm using SailsJs and this is my code

```
update: function (req, res) {
     Cargo.findOne({id: req.param('id')}).exec(function (err,result) {
        result.currency = 2;

        if(err) {
            console.log(err);

        }

        result.save(function(err,model){
            console.log(err);
            console.log(model);
            console.log('in');
        });
        console.log("testing");

    })
},
```

I keep getting "testing" in my console log and not getting any log in save method.
Am I doing it wrong?

Comment: How are you connecting to mongo? Are you using  .createConnection() or .connect() ?

Comment: No. I'm connecting to mysql server. I think let me update my question to show the full controller action

Comment: Which ORM/driver are you using?

Comment: I run this "npm install sails-mysql" to install the driver

Comment: I think I found the issue and solve it. Thanks for helping.

Comment: Please don't edit the solution in your question, instead [post an answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the issue causing it not going into .save method

My model code are as follow

```
module.exports = {
tableName: "cargo",

attributes: {
    'remark': {
        type: 'text'
    },
    'shipper': {
        type: 'integer',
        integer: true,
        model: 'Company',
        columnName:"shipperID",
    },
    'consignee': {
        type: 'integer',
        integer: true,
        columnName:"consigneeID",
        model: 'Company'
    },
    'packing': {
        "type": 'integer',
        integer: true,
        columnName:"packingID",
        equals: function (value) {
            return value;
        }
    },
    'commodity': {
        'type': "string",
        maxLength: 512
    },
    'status': {
        'type': "string",
        maxLength: 25
    },
    'dateIn': {
        'type': "datetime"
    },
    'currency': {
        'type': 'integer'
    },
    'amt': {
        'type': 'float'
    },
    'marking': {
        'type': 'string',
        maxLength: 25,
        required: true
    },
    'createdAt': {
        columnName: 'createdDate'
    },
    'updatedAt': {
        columnName: 'lastModifiedDate'
    },
    'packages': {
        collection: 'CargoPackage',
        via: 'cargo'
    }
}
};
```

It's due to "packing" attribute having this "equal" that cause the save method to goes into infinite loop or something. I thought this is a validator for making sure the value is what I want. Well I think its built for other purposes.

I guess for others with similar issues, it will be best to have the model you are working on be as basic as possible to make sure it's not that thing holding up the process.